# Pandas compare next row and merge based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, merge, conditional-statements

[I have below dataframe. Where START+TIME=END
I want ti check id END of current row = START of next row then merge that 2 rows providing "ID" hsould the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFDuk.png)

So the output should look like,
[So the output is as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9o6P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample DF

```
       Start    Time   End      ID
  0    43500    60     43560    23
  1    43560    60     43620    23 
  2    43620    1020   44640    24 
  3    44640    260    44900    24
  4    44900    2100   47000    24
```

Code:

```
a = df["ID"].tolist()
arr = [] 
t = True
for i in sorted(list(set(a))):
    j = 1
    k = 0
    temp = {}
    tempdf = df[df["ID"] == i]
    temp["Start"] = tempdf.iloc[k]["Start"]
    temp["Time"] = tempdf.iloc[k]["Time"]
    temp["End"] = tempdf.iloc[k]["End"]   
    temp["ID"] = tempdf.iloc[k]["ID"]

    while j < len(tempdf):
        if temp["End"] == tempdf.iloc[j]["Start"]:
            temp["End"] = tempdf.iloc[j]["End"]
            temp["Time"] += tempdf.iloc[j]["Time"] 
         j += 1  
        
    arr.append(temp)       

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Output DF:

```
        Start   Time    End     ID
   0    43500   120     43620   23   
   1    43620   3380    47000   24
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what if i have 4 rows having end = start and with same ID? I want to 4 rows to get merge into 1

Comment: Yah, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data is formatted exactly but you can just replace.
I suggest you use numpy and try something along the lines :

```
i=0
while i != len(data):
    if data[i][4] == data[i+1][2]:
        data[i][4] = data[i+1][2]
        data[i+1].pop
    else :
        i+=1
```